# Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps

There are two coordinate points which are marked on the map. What code should write whatever between these points traced the route as a line, but not directly, but on the roads, without specifying their crotch points?

Comment: whats a "crotch point"?

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Find some Web service that will give you intermediate points, of sufficient granularity, along the desired route between the two end points. I have no idea if such a Web service exists that is publicly available.

Step #2: Use a `Polyline` to connect the intermediate points.

If by "without specifying their crotch points" you mean you do not want to use these intermediate points along your roads, please build a city that has perfectly straight roads, then limit your maps to that city.

Comment: You are right. I need to somehow Contact as these services. I will look in this direction.